# complexity of membership problem in finite general linear group

Tags: computational-complexity, computational-group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a subgroup of $GL(n,q)$ given by a list of generators. What is known about the complexity of the corresponding "membership problem", that is, the problem of deciding whether a given $g \in GL(n,q)$ belongs to $G$ ?

While it would be great to have an actual bound on the complexity, or to know that some other problems reduce to this one, I would also be happy with empirical or even anecdotal evidence.

To me, it seems that the problem is very tractable when $n$ is less than 10 and $q$ is less than 50, but becomes hard very very rapidly. I think trying to compute with $GL(25, 81)$ would be a disaster. What about $n\ge 500$ and $p\ge 10,000$ ?

Comment: I think it's in $\text{NP}\cap\text{coNP}$, see [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/32312/498835).